# Removing transparent area in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have one mask image, this image is transparent and I will change the image size dynamically. The problem is that the image is displayed in a square/rectangle form. The `ImageView` is also displaying the transparent area image, so how to remove the transparent area?

The image is:

[image: Mask Image]

Comment: @Downvoter Give me reason for downvote so i can improve it.

Comment: Dipak, do you have any Idea for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257020/how-to-merge-row-in-one-cell-in-table-layout-in-android-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase size as Imageview size change then you have to set Image as its `background`.

Try using `setBackgroundResource()` you can able to increase your ImageView image

Comment: If I give ImagePath as a Background Resource then Image Resizing, Zoom In, Zoom Out & Rotation is not Performed on Touch Event of ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

for changing the size of image dynamically you can use scale animation,in layout of android.