# ImageView SetImageResource & Resizing Problem

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-rotation, zooming

My Problem is I have One ImageView and I am Set one Image as a setBackgroundResource of Imageview then The Rotation, Zoom In, Zoom Out is not Performed on Touch Event of Image.

Following is My Touch Event Code:-

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == mImageViewMask) {

            System.out.println("Vande Mataram");
            mImageViewMask = (ImageView) v;
            r = Math.atan2(event.getX() - mImageViewMask.getWidth() / 2,
                    mImageViewMask.getHeight() / 2 - event.getY());
            rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {

                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);

                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                            - start.y);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    updateRotation(rotation);
                    newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {

                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;
            }

            // Perform the transformation

            mImageViewMask.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Sorry for Bad English Communication.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: to call this in your activity,setContentView(new MyImageView(this));

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setBackgroundImage, please set the image as source.

Comment: If I set the Image as Source then following Problem is Occured. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430441/imageview-problem-in-android

Comment: Difficult to understand what was your problem in the link? If you can explain that I may be able to answer

Comment: In this Link, the Mask Image is Transparent but if I Set This Image as a BackgroundResource of ImageView, the Only Mask is displayed without Transparent Area. If I set the Mask Image as a SetImageResource then the Transparent Area of Image is also Displayed.