# How to merge row in one cell in Table Layout in android, dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

how to get below functionality in android with Table Layout.
As it is seen in the image, I need to merge the two cells in **row #5 - column #1** and **row#6 - column#1** dynamically and I have to replace one image over there. How can I achieve this? Your answers are appreciated.

[image: merge two cell]

Comment: see this link may be it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681024/how-to-manage-gridview

Comment: Dipak, thanks, then also you can send more and more link for that type of example.

Comment: You don't really need to "merge" two cell, replace both image  individually should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use GridLayout instead of TableLayout. You can easily merge cells using GridLayout.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html